# MapField with Points

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I want to make a screen where i have to show the map with the all received lat and long. and i want to show this map in 200*200 resolution only.

Can i make the point bitmap as focusable so i can be click on it and show other screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to show more than one location in Blackberry MapField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554016/how-to-show-more-than-one-location-in-blackberry-mapfield)

hope this link helps you in solving your problem;Do you have any idea how to display a small text box kind of thing when multiple points are selected?