# How to show multiple locations in Blackberry Rich Map Field

Tags: blackberry

I getting location lattitude and longitude values from webservice.Now i have to display those locations on Blackberry Rich Map Field.And i also switch to other screen when particular location is clicked.How can i display multiple locations in BB Rich Map Field.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only solution is to override paint method of mapfiled to show multiple markers.
Check this out:
[How to show more than one location in Blackberry MapField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554016/how-to-show-more-than-one-location-in-blackberry-mapfield)