# Able to Show several location in blackberry maps but the position of maps is fixed. I am not able to zoom in and zoom out

Tags: blackberry, maps

Hi everyone I tried using the Custom MapField to show several loacations on map. I am able to show the locations on map. But not able to move the image and also cant zoom in and zoom out.i tried using custom MapField but still it is not working for me..
Here is my code for that

```
class CustomMapField extends MapField 
{
Bitmap mIcon;
XYRect mDest;
public void moveTo(Coordinates coordinates) 
{
    super.moveTo(coordinates);
    mDest = null;
}
protected void paint(Graphics graphics) 
{
    super.paint(graphics);
    if (null != mIcon) 
    {
        if (null == mDest) 
        {
            XYPoint fieldOut = new XYPoint();
            convertWorldToField(getCoordinates(), fieldOut);
            int imgW = mIcon.getWidth();
            int imgH = mIcon.getHeight();
            mDest = new XYRect(fieldOut.x - imgW / 2,fieldOut.y - imgH, imgW, imgH);
        }
        graphics.drawBitmap(mDest, mIcon, 0, 0);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What OS version are you targeting?

Comment: Check this link..   

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554016/how-to-show-more-than-one-location-in-blackberry-mapfield

Comment: @jprofitt version 5 and above.

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to implement zoom and pan on your own. It is possible (I've done it), but does require a fair amount of code to make it work with touch and trackwheel devices.

Comment: Hey thanks alot.. can you help me with some code plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for zoom in and zoom out I used this-

```
 public boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time) 
{    
    if(key=='i')
    {
        mMapField.setZoom(Math.max(mMapField.getZoom() - 1,mMapField.getMinZoom()));
    }
    else if(key=='o')
    {
        mMapField.setZoom(Math.min(mMapField.getZoom() + 1,mMapField.getMaxZoom()));
    }
    return super.keyChar(key, status, time);
}
```