# is it possible to move the map on touch in blackberry by using MapField.

Tags: blackberry, maps

I am using mapField to create a custom map.I am using the code in this link.
    [How to show more than one location in Blackberry MapField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554016/how-to-show-more-than-one-location-in-blackberry-mapfield).
But the map position is fixed. i am not able to drag the map as we can do in google maps or when we invoke the maps like

```
 public void execute(ReadOnlyCommandMetadata metadata, Object context) 
        {
            Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MAPS, new MapsArguments());
        }
```

Comment: i am just trying it out on the JDE simulator. version 6.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some code that should get you going on the correct path. I've taken it from a project of mine that had some special requirements, so there could be some remnants of that left in there inadvertently. There will be some undefined variables in there -- they're member variables that are declared in the class and should all start with an underscore. This is also part of a class that extends `MapField`, so you would have to create a custom map class and then use that rather than the default.

```java
protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {
    boolean ret =  super.touchEvent(message);

    //mark that we're starting to interact
    if(message.getEvent() == TouchEvent.DOWN) {
        _startTouchTracking = true;
        _clicking = true;

        _touchX = message.getX(1);
        _touchY = message.getY(1);

    }
    //user is wanting to move the map
    else if(message.getEvent() == TouchEvent.MOVE) {
        int dx = _touchX - message.getX(1);
        int dy = _touchY - message.getY(1);
        _clicking = false;
        _touchX = message.getX(1);
        _touchY = message.getY(1);

        //perform checks to make sure we don't move outside of the map's range
        int lat = getLatitude() - dy*(int)MathUtilities.pow(2, (double)getZoom());
        if(lat < -9000000) {
            lat = -9000000;
        }
        else if (lat > 9000000) {
            lat = 9000000;
        }
        int lon = getLongitude() + dx*(int)MathUtilities.pow(2, (double)getZoom());
        if(lon < -18000000) {
            lon = -18000000;
        }
        else if (lon > 18000000) {
            lon = 18000000;
        }

        moveTo(lat, lon);
    }
    //if the person just touches and releases, we want to move to that spot
    else if (message.getEvent() == TouchEvent.UNCLICK && _clicking) {
        int dx = message.getX(1) - getWidth()/2;
        int dy = message.getY(1) - getHeight()/2;
        move(dx, dy);
        _clicking = false;
    }
    //touch has been released
    else if (message.getEvent() == TouchEvent.UP) {
        _startTouchTracking = false;
    }
    //we handled the click
    return true;
}
```

As said, this might need tweaking for your use, but in general should get you started. The `MathUtilities.pow()` calls were my way of coming up with an appropriate amount of motion depending on the zoom level.

**Edit for Comments**

Letting a Bitmap move with the map:

```java
protected Coordinates _bitmapCoordinates;
protected Bitmap _bitmap;
public YourMapField() {
    //we're going to put the bitmap at -38.43, 20.32
    _bitmapCoordinates = new Coordinates(-38.43, 20.32, 0.0);
    _bitmap = YOUR_CODE_TO_GET_THE_BITMAP;
}

protected void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    XYPoint placeToPaintBitmap = new XYPoint();
    convertWorldToField(_bitmapCoordinates, placeToPaintBitmap);

    //perform a check here to make sure that field will be seen. This code would depend
    //on how you're painting the image. Just check the placeToPaintBitmap.x and placeToPaintBitmap.y
    //against 0 and the map's width and height, along with some adjustment for how you paint
    if(bitmap will be visible on the screen) {

        //The code I have here is drawing the bitmap from the top left of the image, but if
        //you need to draw from some other place you may have to offset the x and y 
        g.drawBitmap(placeToPaintBitmap.x, placeToPaintBitmap.y, _bitmap.getWidth(), _bitmap.getHeight(), 0, 0);
    }
}
```

I didn't test any of that code, so it might be buggy but should give you the general idea.

Comment: hi profitt.. its moving the mapField but to a particular point only and when I try to move the screen again its not moving

Comment: I changed the line `move(lat, lon)` to `moveTo(lat, lon)`, see if that fixes it.

Comment: hey thanks.. its working f9 nw.. One more thing I wanted to know. I am placing the bitmap on top of the map. but it is fixed and i want it to move with the map.. Please help

Comment: If your Bitmap is being placed at a certain coordinate, you can use `MapField.convertWorldToField(Coordinates bitmapLatLon, XYPoint placeToPaintTheBitmap)` and then check if `placeToPaintTheBitmap`, which will give you an (x, y) location in pixels that relates to the same (lat, lon) location, will be viewable.

Comment: ya i am placing it at certain coordinate.Can you please explain what is this placeToPaintTheBitmap ?

Comment: It will be the spot you use in your `paint()` method to paint it on the screen.

Comment: hey can you please help me with some code I am new to blackberry

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6038/discussion-between-swati-and-jprofitt)

Comment: thanxx alot.. actually I am already checking the bitmap visibility but problem come when I am moving the Map or you can say dragging the Map

Comment: hey another problem is occurring.. by the time map loads the bitmap placed over the Mapfield move alone and the map doesn't move. Please help

Comment: Hmm, maybe call `invalidate()` on the map when you move.

Comment: hi.. i need one more help.. i have mentioned how i am drawing the bitmap can u help me how to trace the event on that bitmap.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "trace the event"

Comment: I am mean i want to take action on click on the bitmap. Is it possible?

Comment: Yeah, you have to do some calculations in the touchEvent() to determine what the bounds of each bitmap would be on the screen using the `worldToField()` and `fieldToWorld()` methods.