# Blackberry map with custom markers

Tags: blackberry, maps, markers

How to create blackberry map with two types of markers - first for search results, clickable, leading to detail screen and second just for current location (not clickable, visually different)

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

I know it is late, buit still I am posting because it might help someone else. Check out the below link

[How to show our own icon in BlackBerry Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524428/how-to-show-our-own-icon-in-blackberry-map)